# calling a method from a fragment inside a mainactivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now and still cant figure it out. I've checked many similiar topics about this but didnt get me what I need.

As you can see I'm adding the fragments dynamically:

```
  public void displayFragment1() {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_1(), "frag1");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}

public void displayFragment2() {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_2(), "frag2");
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


}
```

Here is the part that I cant figure out. I'm searching the fragments by tag and it seems that its not working since I'm always getting nullpointer exception or classexception. Toast just shows the value of the text that I entered so its sending the data from a fragment to the activity. so that part is fine. Any ideas guys???

```
 @Override
public void inputValue(String text) {

    if (text != null) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_2(), "frag2");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment_2 fragment = (Fragment_2) fm.findFragmentByTag("frag2");
        fragment.setChangeTo(text);


    } else {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "didnt recieve the value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }


}
```

activity main xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.neven.question_for_stackoverflow.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background">

<FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:id="@+id/fragment_container">

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment_1.sendData {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    displayFragment1();
}
```

fragment 1 xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example.neven.question_for_stackoverflow.Fragment_1"
         android:background="@drawable/my_background">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="fragment 1"
        android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etInputID" android:layout_gravity="center" android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="enter text here" android:textColorHint="#e3ca0a"/>
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        android:id="@+id/bSendID" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="130dp"/>
```

fragment 2 xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         tools:context="com.example.neven.question_for_stackoverflow.Fragment_2"
         android:background="@drawable/my_background">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="fragment 2 - change me"
        android:id="@+id/tvChangeMeID" android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: Please show your layout XML where you define the fragment or its `Framelayout` - we need to confirm the `id` attribute of your framelayout - this is the `id` you would use with `findFragmentById(id)` method.

Comment: I'm using the default one (android.R.id.content)

Comment: Hi, please update your question by including the layout XML file and also show us the `onCreate` method of your `Activity` - we need to examine these and suggest solutions to your problem.

Comment: I updated my topic

Comment: @Nenco Try to create activities which extends `Fragment` and then call `FragmentTransaction` after `FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are calling `displayFragment1();` in your Activity's `onCreate` and yet you are expecting to find `Fragment_2` which you are only setting/initializing in `displayFragment2();` - you never call this method.
So, please change your code in the `onCreate` method to call `displayFragment2()` like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    displayFragment2();
}
```

UPDATE:
Please add the call `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after the commit statement and then try looking up the `Fragment` by TAG and see if this at least returns a `Fragment` object and not null. Your code will now look like:

```
...
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new Fragment_2(), "frag2");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()

    Fragment_2 fragment = (Fragment_2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("frag2");
    fragment.setChangeTo(text);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thats not the issues, I will update the topic with fragment1 and 2 xmls sec

Comment: so as you see I need to display the fragment 1 first cause I make an input there. and when I click on send it goes to the 2nd fragment where that input shows in a textview. To do that I'm calling the setChangeTo method from fragment 2 inside my mainactivity.

Comment: OK, noted. I have updated my answer, please try it out and let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a FrameLayout in your Activity's layout xml where the fragments you want will be inflated. Then use that FrameLayout's id when making a transaction instead of android.R.id.content.

Comment: its the same effect If I use the default one or the one I create. I tried your suggestion with fragment container and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this is:

```
Fragment fragment = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container); 
if (fragment instanceof    YourFragmentClass) {
fragment.setChangeTo(value);
}
```