# Why is my FrameLayout fragment_container null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

As written in the [Android Developer's Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace), I have programmatically created a `FrameLayout` that serves as the `fragment_container` of `Fragment`s that are to be replaced frequently.  I have encountered a `NullPointerException` that says that I'm trying to invoke a method on a null pointer, but I don't see how I'm supposed to fix this problem.  Any ideas?

## Problematic Code

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
                // the fragment_container FrameLayout
                if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {
                    // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
                    BlankFragment firstFragment = new BlankFragment();


                    // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment.newInstance("","")).commit();
                    blankFragment.setThumbnail(thumbnails.get(finalI).getDrawable());
                }
                else    {
                    FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
                    BlankFragment blankFragment = new BlankFragment();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, blankFragment).commit();
                    blankFragment.setThumbnail(thumbnails.get(finalI).getDrawable());
                }
```

## BlankFragment.newInstance()

```
public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

## FrameLayout in Question

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/horizontal_scroll"></FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a static method `BlankFragment.newInstance()` which you're not using (correctly). Instead you're creating your fragments with `new BlankFragment()`. This leads to a state where you access arguments you've never set since `getArguments()` returns `null` by default.

Also calling `firstFragment.newInstance("","")` isn't a correct way to do, what you're trying to do. You don't need to and should not create a new instance to call a static method. Just do `BlankFragment.newInstance("","")` directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar example where I add fragments dynamically and was getting nullpointer exception or classexception errors until I got a solution.

check it out:

[calling a method from a fragment inside a mainactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37308871/calling-a-method-from-a-fragment-inside-a-mainactivity)